# find all the ejbs deployed on weblogic application

Tags: ejb, weblogic, jndi

I have a requirement to list all the ejbs and their jndi names that are currently deployed on an application running on weblogic 12 server.

Is there a way to get that information.

Thanks
gmk

Comment: Have you tried to access the JNDI [tree panel](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/jndi/ViewObjectsInTheJNDITree.html) ?

Comment: I can view the entire JNDI tree. But how to get the entire JNDI dump through a program.

Answer (score 0):

All the tools you need to do this can be found in [javax.naming.Context](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/naming/Context.html) and friends.

In particular, look at [javax.naming.Context.list(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/naming/Context.html#list-java.lang.String-) and [javax.naming.Context.listBindings(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/naming/Context.html#listBindings-java.lang.String-) methods.